# Menu went wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my database

```
   ID          parentitemid        text                Url
   1            NULL           folder1         /folder1
   2            folder1     WebForm1.aspx   /folder1/WebForm1.aspx
   3            folder1     WebForm2.aspx   /folder1/WebForm2.aspx
   6              null          folder3     /folder3
   7            folder3     WebForm1.aspx   /folder3/WebForm1.aspx
   8            folder3     WebForm2.aspx   /folder3/WebForm2.aspx
   9            folder3     WebForm3.aspx   /folder3/WebFomr3.aspx
```

I'm trying to build a menu out of this......

So it should look something like folder1(WebFrom1.aspx, WebForm2.aspx) and so on. But it went completely wrong and prints folder1(folder1), folder3(folder3),folder1(folder1) ....

- folder1 (folder 1) says that folder1 is the menu and folder1 in the brackets is the submenu.

This is my logic in codebehind

```
  if (!IsPostBack)
{
    DataSet dst = GetMenuData();
    foreach (DataRow masterRow in dst.Tables["Menu"].Rows)
    {
        if ((string)masterRow["parentitemid"] != "NULL" ||
            (string)masterRow["parentitemid"] != "")
        {
            MenuItem masterItem = new MenuItem((string)masterRow["parentitemid"]);
            Menu1.Items.Add(masterItem);
            foreach (DataRow childRow in masterRow.GetChildRows("Menu"))
            {
                MenuItem childItem = new MenuItem((string)childRow["text"]);
                masterItem.ChildItems.Add(childItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
  DataSet GetMenuData()
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=NISHANTH-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial     
   Catalog=roletesting;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter parent = new SqlDataAdapter("Select DISTINCT parentitemid from 
    Menu", con);
        SqlDataAdapter child = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Menu", con);
        DataSet dst = new DataSet();
        parent.Fill(dst, "Menu");
        child.Fill(dst, "Menu");
        dst.Relations.Add("Children",
            dst.Tables["Menu"].Columns["parentitemid"],
        dst.Tables["Menu"].Columns["text"],false
      );
        return dst;
    }
```

Can u please help me in filling the menu correctly..

Comment: If you have control of the database, I would recommend having the parent column pointing to the ID, instead of the text column. This will allow you to change the folder names without having to update all the parentitemid cells.

Comment: Please don't add "C#" to your titles just to put your question into a category. We use tags for that on [SO].

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data retrieval is your first issue.  It looks like you'll retrieve your parent data then immediately overwrite the Menu table with the child data.  This then looks to relate your one table to itself on a one-to-one basis.

Try changing your Fills to different table names and work from there...

```
        parent.Fill(dst, "Menu");
        child.Fill(dst, "SubMenu");
```

Comment: So, I need to create another table and have a relation between  menu and submenu

Comment: Yep. parent and child are two separate commands for getting data, but both are trying to put that data into the same table name within the same dataset, causing it to overwrite.

Comment: Can u say the best way to divide my tables

Comment: Best division could work many ways and will depend on your needs.  Is this a get youre feet wet class project or a commercial website you intend to grow for years?  If your menus will never be more than one level deep, you may better off mirroring that in your DB with a parent and child table (keyed to key rather than names as suggested above).  If submenus can have children, your basic idea works for the hierarchical nature.  I'd suggest some mechanism to represent the arrangement of your menu items.